# How to set up head in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

I added some themekit CSS to Next.js head, but browser console raise warning, what is wrong?

```
Expected server HTML to contain a matching <head> in <div>.
```

```js
const Layout = ({ children, isNavbarTransparent }: Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/bootstrap-grid.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/style.css" />
                <script src="themekit/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="themekit/scripts/main.js"></script>
            </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using HTML [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head). Instead use [Head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) component from Next.js, as they suggest in their documentation.

> We expose a built-in component for appending elements to the head of the page.

```js
import Head from "next/head";

const Layout = ({ children, isNavbarTransparent }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/bootstrap-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/style.css" />
        <script src="themekit/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="themekit/scripts/main.js"></script>
      </Head>
```